# Java, comparing value of two string arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, equals

I am trying to complete an assignment for school and I'm having issues seeing if each element in two String arrays are equal.  I have looked everywhere and it seems like I'm already doing it correctly but it is not.

Real quick, the assignment is user enters in the quiz number and the solutions to a T/F quiz (2 T T T F F...) and then enters in info for a student, a first, last name, student ID and their answers to that quiz.

**If I enter in 1 T T T F F T T for the answer key and T T T F F F F for the students answers it counts them all as equal and I can't figure out why.   I will post all my code but add stars around the appropriate for loop where I *think* the problem is...**  Thank you for any help, this is driving me crazy!

```
public class CST200_Lab4 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String inputValue = " ";
    String answerKey [];
    String firstName = " ";
    String lastName = " ";
    String IDnumber = " ";
    int studentResults = 0;
    int numStudents = 0;
    double averageScore = 0;


    InputStreamReader ISR = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(ISR);

    //Read in the Answer Key to the Quiz w/ quiz number at index 0.
    String answers = BR.readLine();
    answerKey = answers.split(" "); 
    /*Read in Students info and students quiz results.
     *Set size of student array to length of the answer key */
    String studentArr[] = new String [answerKey.length + 4];
    inputValue = BR.readLine();
    studentArr = inputValue.split("\\s+");

    //Enter students info until 'zzzz' is entered.
    while(!(inputValue.equalsIgnoreCase("ZZZZ"))) {         

        //Keep track of student(s) entered to calculate average scores.
        numStudents++;

        //quizResults = inputValue.replaceAll("^(\\S*\\s){4}", "");
        //quizResultsArr = quizResults.split("\\s+");

        //Set students info to first three indexes of studentArr.
        lastName = studentArr[0];
        firstName = studentArr[1];
        IDnumber = studentArr[2];

        /*Loop through answerKey and compare w/ student quiz results 
         *to determine how many questions the student got correct*/


    //I THINK THE ISSUE IS IN HERE BUT I CAN'T FIGURE OUT WHY 
    ******************************************************************************      
         for(int i = 1; i < studentArr.length - 2; i++) {
            //ALL 'ANSWERS' ARE BEING COUNTED AS EQUAL
            if((studentArr[i + 2]).equalsIgnoreCase(answerKey[i])); {
                studentResults++;   
                averageScore++;
            }
        }   
     ******************************************************************************

        //Print out Students info and results.
        lastName.replace(",", " ");
        System.out.print(IDnumber + "  ");
        System.out.print(firstName);
        System.out.print(lastName + " ");
        System.out.println(studentResults);
        System.out.println(averageScore);

        //Enter a new students info or 'zzzz' to end
        studentResults = 0; 
        inputValue = BR.readLine();
        studentArr = inputValue.split("\\s+");

    }
    /*If no more students are being entered, 
     *calculate average score of test results.*/
    System.out.println(numStudents);
    System.out.println(averageScore);
    if(inputValue.equalsIgnoreCase("ZZZZ")) {
        averageScore = averageScore / numStudents;
        System.out.println("The average score is " + averageScore );
    }           
}
}
```

Comment: Remove that semicolon following the `if` condition.

Comment: Classic typo.  Time to close the question.

Answer (score 4):

```
if((studentArr[i + 2]).equalsIgnoreCase(answerKey[i]));
```

Should not end a conditional if statement with ;

Comment: WOW!  I've been wasting hours because of that stupid typo lol.  Thanks!  I'm glad it was just my stupidity

Comment: I have to wait a few more minutes to except your answer.